Ошибка systemctl не запускает скрипт python
пишу эти команды
Description=Bot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/root/poizon2
ExecStart=python3 /root/poizon2/app.py

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s

далее запускаю сервер
systemctl enable owlreal_bot.service

Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/owlreal_bot.service -> /etc/systemd/system/owlreal_bot.service.

(venv) root@owlreal:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl start owlreal_bot.service

но когда смотрю статус вылетает такая ошибка
root@owlreal:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status owlreal_bot.service
* owlreal_bot.service - Bot

     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/owlreal_bot.service; enabled; preset: enabled)

     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-08-09 21:20:19 UTC; 3s ago

    Process: 2089 ExecStart=python3 /root/poizon2/app.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

   Main PID: 2089 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

        CPU: 88ms

Aug 09 21:20:19 owlreal systemd[1]: owlreal_bot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Aug 09 21:20:19 owlreal systemd[1]: owlreal_bot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

подскажите пожалуйста что может быть не так
